# window.open within electron webview

Tags: javascript, electron, window.open

I have a webview inside my app that I primarily use to access external websites.

One particular **external website** has some JS in its page:

```
newWin = window.open("https://google.com");
settimer = setInterval(counting, 500);
function counting() {
  if (newWin.closed) {
    clearInterval(settimer);
    console.log('closed')
  } else {
    console.log('still open')
  }
```

I have the `allowpopups` attribute on so this code opens a new window, but I would like to get control of this window. I am not sure how to do that.

Specifically I would like to mute the window and hide the window as well as be able to close it.

**How can I get control of a popup opened through a webview?**

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at Electron's [`window.open`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/window-open.md). It's different from the native window.open and I would assume that the webview will also use the Electron one.